# webpack did not output file to correct directory

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, webpack, gulp

I try to implement hot reloading in a laravel app. But I have problem doing output using webpack. When I do http://localhost/bundle.js it's 404 not found. I wonder why. In my terminal I did see bundle.js is bundled by webpack, but where has it gone to?

gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.dev.config');
var bundler = webpack(webpackConfig);
    gulp.task('hot', function(){

        elixir(function(mix) {

            browserSync({ 
              proxy: 'somewhere.local',
              middleware: [
                webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
                  publicPath: '/'
                }),

                webpackHotMiddleware(bundler)
              ]
            });
        });
    });
```

webpack.dev.config.js **The problem is here**

```
module.exports = {
  debug: true,
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'resources/assets/bundle/entries'),
  entry: ['./feed.js'],
  output: {
    path     : path.join(__dirname, 'public/bundle'),
    publicPath : '/',
    filename : 'bundle.js'
  }
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
}
```

my laravel view

I also included

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/bundle.js"></script>
```

Something is wrong in my webpack config file. Here's my site directory :
[image]

Comment: Your `bundle` is located in `public/bundle/bundle.js`., based on your script, you are trying load script from root directory, that is not correct.

Comment: @Aexander T. how should it be? bundle.js is not a physical file, look at this example https://github.com/eriksape/laravel-react-hot-loader/blob/master/webpack.config.js. You convert feed.js and many other files to bundle.js then you can do hot reloading with browsersync

Comment: Means my path value is incorrect? please help. I see nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

webpack dev server doesn't write the bundle to disk.

> This modified bundle is served from memory at the relative path specified in publicPath (see API). It will not be written to your configured output directory. Where a bundle already exists at the same URL path, the bundle in memory takes precedence (by default).

you can find out more here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

depending on your exact needs, you might consider using a different webpack configuration